# EJS server sided template is it safe?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ejs

For example this block of code is embedded in my test.ejs file,

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<ul>
<% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
    <li><%= supplies[i] %></li>
<% } %>
</ul>
```

The template will get rendered and will be sent to client as a HTML file with the loop already executed.

Lets say I only want the client to see 3 of the supplies so I would do

```
 <% for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {%>
```

instead of

```
 <% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
```

How safe is this? Can the client somehow change the number 3 and put in `supplies.length` so the browser will render the data accordingly? I am new to NodeJS so what I normally do is I would query the data to MongoDB so that only 3 of the supplies is returned before passing it to EJS. But just out of curiosity, is this kind of template safe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running EJS within nodejs on the server side then it is safe. The entire execution happens on the server side and the client cannot modify the loop. In fact, the client has no way of knowing the HTML was produced with a for loop at all.